# Microchip PIC24F & Android device: Which can be host device?

Tags: pic, communication, android, host

I work on a project where I want to connect PIC24F (Accessory Development Kit for Android [www.microchip.com/android](http://www.microchip.com/android)) and Samsung Galaxy S2 that I updated from android 2.3.3 to android version 2.3.4.
I loaded firmware to the PIC24F and Demo app to Galaxy.
When I connect devices my galaxy still says: "Device not connected".

Does Samsung Galaxy S2 can be a host for PIC24F or is this hardware-dependent?

Does anybody know if it is possible for PIC24F to act as a host instead of android device?

Comment: The PIC24F Accessory Development Starter Kit for Android™ (DM240415) uses the [PIC24FJGB110](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en531089), which can act as a USB host -- "Dual role capable, can act as either Host or Device".

Answer (score 1):

You will need to attempt debugging from the PIC side.

The PIC acts as a USB host.  When it runs, it should connect to the android device.

Check your code to make sure it doesn't need to be modified to specifically recognize the VID/PID of this android device.

Then step through the code and see if the USB host is connecting to the android device, and if so whether it's sending or receiving on any of the USB pipes.

I suspect it'll be an issue of configuration in the software.  The PIC ADK software lists devices it supports, but you probably need to add an entry in the code configuration file to allow it to attempt to connect to the S2.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy S2 doesn't appear to be supported:

http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2919&param=en546070

Comment: The embedded implementation of the ADB protocol (which slightly preceded the ADK) would be an option compatible with any normal any Android device.